# Types for a function that receives an optional propertyName as parameter and returns either that property's value of an object or the full object

Tags: javascript, typescript, properties, type-inference, typescript-generics

Function that gets an optional parameter `propName` which should be a `key` of `SOME_OBJECT` and either returns the `propName` value, if `propName` is passed, or the full `OBJECT` if `propName` is `undefined`:

This is the code:

```
type SOME_OBJECT = {
  propA: string,
  propB: number,
}

const getPropertyOrFullObject = <K extends keyof SOME_OBJECT>(propName?: K)
: SOME_OBJECT[K] | SOME_OBJECT => {

  const myData: SOME_OBJECT = {  // IN REAL CASE, SOME_OBJECT WILL COME FROM ANOTHER PLACE
    propA: "fooA",
    propB: 42
  };

  if (propName) {
    return myData[propName];
  }
  else {
    return myData;
  }
};

const propA = getPropertyOrFullObject("propA");  // EXPECT IT TO BE string
const propB = getPropertyOrFullObject("propB");  // EXPECT IT TO BE number
const fullObj = getPropertyOrFullObject();       // EXPECT IT TO BE SOME_OBJECT
```

Code available on [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg8gWQKIH04CEBSSDCAVKAXigG8AoKKMAJwHswBBALigGdhqBLAOwHMAaClTph0LbgFcAtgCMI1QQF8yZAMa1u7WIlQZs+FvGRosuAsXKUa9ZlABEAM1q0GdwVZFioAFgBMZRQBuFXVNYCheCGAABRF5UDhqADEJABtUuBkAKwhVcOIAHgBpKAgAD2AIbgATVigAawgQWgdtYz0zAD4ACmswADkAQykIAH4WIoBKMkMdE308AG0igF0oAB823VN8Ik7SFUpQrSNthdn2nfMDyg8bFkdnV3dbvq8-ISDDqE5W3pEhiNJjdbtQohJqNwtvMzIs+oCICtgpRlJQIKlWNBLKDwZDoR18MioMovmoNFo+gwiBEorF6PEQIkUulMjk8t07JS7JNgsdwm9qZEYnFqAlkmkMtlcsAOW9ubzyeEHBLWYLaSKxczJWyZTygA)

I'm not getting what I'm expecting. I'm getting union types instead. Look:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

that's because TS is unable to figure out what your function will return exactly. TS merges all possible returns.

To make it more straightforward, it is a good practice to overload your function.

Take a look on example:

```js
type SOME_OBJECT = {
  propA: string,
  propB: number,
}

// here is new player
interface Overloading {
  <K extends keyof SOME_OBJECT>(propName: K): SOME_OBJECT[K]
  (): SOME_OBJECT;
}

const getPropertyOrFullObject: Overloading  = <K extends keyof SOME_OBJECT>(propName?: K)
: SOME_OBJECT[K] | SOME_OBJECT => {

  const myData: SOME_OBJECT = {  // IN REAL CASE, SOME_OBJECT WILL COME FROM ANOTHER PLACE
    propA: "fooA",
    propB: 42
  };

  if (propName) {
    const r = myData[propName]
    return myData[propName];
  }
  else {
    return myData;
  }
};

const propA = getPropertyOrFullObject("propA");  // string
const propB = getPropertyOrFullObject("propB");  //  number
const fullObj = getPropertyOrFullObject();       // SOME_OBJECT
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if I can do the same with a custom type guard? Example: check `propertyName` into a `isPropertyOfSomeObject` function that will return `propertyName is key of SOME_OBJECT`. Or something similar.

Comment: Please share your example in new typescriptp layground and update your question. I'll try to help

Answer (score 0):

Based on @captain-yossarian's answer, I ended up doing the following:

```
type SOME_OBJECT = {
  propA: string,
  propB: number,
}

function getPropertyOrFullObject(): SOME_OBJECT;
function getPropertyOrFullObject<K extends keyof SOME_OBJECT>(propName: K): SOME_OBJECT[K];
function getPropertyOrFullObject<K extends keyof SOME_OBJECT>(propName?: K): SOME_OBJECT | SOME_OBJECT[K] {

  const SOME_OBJECT: SOME_OBJECT = {  // IN REAL CASE, THIS WILL COME FROM ELSEWHERE
    propA: "fooA",
    propB: 42
  };

  return propName ? 
    SOME_OBJECT[propName] 
  : SOME_OBJECT;

}

const propA = getPropertyOrFullObject("propA");   // THIS IS string
const propB = getPropertyOrFullObject("propB");   // THIS IS number
const fullObj = getPropertyOrFullObject();        // THIS IS SOME_OBJECT
```

I think it makes the overload more readable and easier to understand.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg8gWQKIH04CEBSSDCAVKAXigG8AoKKMAJwHswBBALigGdhqBLAOwHMAaClTph0LbgFcAtgCMI1QQF8yZAGYTuAY2Cda3KLwjAACiPmg41AGISANrbgyAVhG0AKAJQt4yNFlx4ANxqGtq6+oYmZtQW1nYOzq7AADwA0lAQAB7AENwAJqxQANYQILSqsIioGNj4AHxuNPQAcgCGUhAsqV6VvjUBANqpALrB6lo6egZGpvTmIJY29o4u2mkZ2bkFxaXlvdX+9Y0ibR0A-F09Pge1BAA++363Q8OkQpp67I-9+N5VTwEiG9KJQmowWAAiVS0WgMCGCEHCehiKAAFgATEJFMEhJwKscWu0IB5gSDqEYJNR9NcAfgBmDThBRlihBBbKxoOREeTgJTqf8fkEWcoyB9uF8wQwgZFZpAYgs4stEu4IZKIR5gmKJSJ0NKZtFYksEqtgG5VTr1ZrPsAoOolU49VE5vLFvEVklPIEgA)